# jQuery Validation based on input type = radio/checkbox/select

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Here's my code

```
$('.f1 .btn-next').on('click', function() {
    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;
    // navigation steps / progress steps
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-step.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    // fields validation
    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], select').each(function() {
         if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
            next_step = false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });
    // fields validation
```

Its a kind of Validation which i'm using in my [Multi-step Form](https://azmind.com/bootstrap-wizard-tutorial-new-step/), here the input text field validation is working perfectly but for Select/Checkbox/Radio, its not working, Please help me to fix the code.

I already tried this code but it's not working for select field -

```
parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], select', '.sys').each(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
  parent_fieldset.find(':input').each(function() {
      //Your code goes here.
     }
//Try this one another way to validate form fields

     var allFormData = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
       for(var dataIndex = 0 ; dataIndex < allFormData.length ; dataIndex++){
         if(allFormData[dataIndex].value == ""){
          $("#myForm input[name="+allFormData[dataIndex].name+"]").addClass("input-error");
         }else{
            $("#myForm input[name="+allFormData[dataIndex].name+"]").removeClass('input-error');
         }
       }
```

Comment: Why the colon in front of `input`?

Comment: @BobRodes The colon will find all form input elements and it is faster

Comment: Ok, just looked it up. Thanks! Now, according to the jQuery doc it's actually slower, but you need it to include `select` inputs. http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: @BobRodes, Yes, it is slower than the normal DOM selector, thanks for the correction

Comment: its not working because (:input) works with whole form validation and i need this validation under fieldset tag container, that's why i'm unable to move to 2nd Setp of this multi-step form...

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that you only want inputs whose type is text, so that's what you're getting. If you want every type of input, just take the type specification away from the selector, like this:

```
parent_fieldset.find(':input').each(function() {

}
```

Edit: the jQuery `:input` extension will include select elements, while `input` will not. The jQuery doc is [here](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

Comment: Its not working in my end, that validation is working but i'm unable to move to 2nd step..!

Comment: @ChetanSoni I suggest that you spend some time getting as clear a picture as you can of why you can't move to the second step, and then ask another question about it, explaining as clearly as you can what the problem is. "It's not working" doesn't give anyone any clues about what's wrong, so nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my final code which works perfectly with all select, radio, checkbox fields

```
parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], select', '.sys').each(function(key, value) {
```